# Windows remote smb connection over port 4450

Tags: windows, nas, port, smb, remapping

I have a NAS and I used to access it remotely but my ISP started to block low ports as 20, 21, 22, 80, 139, 443, 445, etc... So I did some port remapping on my router to accept SMB connections over port 4450 and route to port 445 to the NAS.

In mac, linux and smartphone SMB clients I can connect perfectly like smb://my.home.ip:4450 but I can't get this working on windows.

How can I specify (in windows) the port I want use to connect via SMB?

I've tried in cmd `net use * \\my.home.ip@4450` or `net use * \\my.home.ip:4450` also tried `net use * \\my.dyndns.name@4450` and `net use * \\my.dyndns.name:4450` but nothing worked.

What can I do to access my NAS remotely via SMB on port 4450 from windows client?

Comment: Just a note: exposing SMB ports out towards internet is a really bad idea. (and your ISP intentionally blocking port 445 for SMB is for good reason. No one should even try to "map" your home PC over internet). Have you considered using VPN to your home network, and then doing SMB from there? Or use some other remote connection software (like TeamViewer for example - note: not related to TeamViewer besides a happy customer)

Comment: Yeah @Darius, you're correct at all! I know that expose smb is insecure and my first insight was to create a VPN. I tried to install pptpd on my debian NAS but with no success.
What is better: configure a VPN server in my NAS or there is some kind of paid service that I just install a server software in my NAS that came configured?

You know how to configure VPN software in debian? No need forward to the rest of my LAN. Just to access the NAS files.

Thank you

Comment: @Darius I made openvpn work now, but the smb connection is too slow over the VPN. the vpn is over udp, but seems like smb is running over tcp

Comment: If you only need the files - and VPN is too slow - maybe SFTP?

Comment: @Darius, the SMB over VPN was too slow, so I got everything working with FTP over the VPN. Thank you for the tips!